# Is my proof about the rank of a matrix correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

**The problem:** Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix. Show that $\text{rank}({A})$ is identical to the largest number $k\in\{1,2\dots,\min(m,n)\}$ such that the subdeterminant with $i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $j_1<j_2<\dots<j_k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{i_1j_1} & a_{i_1j_2} & \dots & a_{i_1j_k}\\
a_{i_2j_1} & a_{i_2j_2} & \dots & a_{i_2j_k}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_{i_kj_1} & a_{i_kj_2} & \dots & a_{i_kj_k}
\end{vmatrix}\neq 0.
\end{equation}

**My proof attempt:** Let $\text{rank}(A)=k$. Now I show that the set of indices is maximal.

Suppose $\exists i_1<\dots<i_{k+1}\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\exists j_1<\dots<j_{k+1}\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{i_1j_1} & a_{i_1j_2} & \dots & a_{i_1j_{k+1}}\\
a_{i_2j_1} & a_{i_2j_2} & \dots & a_{i_2j_{k+1}}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_{i_{k+1}j_1} & a_{i_{k+1}j_2} & \dots & a_{i_{k+1}j_{k+1}}
\end{vmatrix}\neq 0.
\end{equation}

Since the determinant is  not equal to zero, the vectors
$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{i_1j_1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{i_{k+1}j_1}
\end{pmatrix},\dots,
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{i_1j_{k+1}}\\
\vdots\\
a_{i_{k+1}j_{k+1}}
\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent. This implies that the column vectors
$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1j_1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{mj_1}
\end{pmatrix},\dots,
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1j_{k+1}}\\
\vdots\\
a_{mj_{k+1}}
\end{pmatrix}$ of the matrix $A$ are also linearly independent. By definition of the rank of a matrix we can conclude that $\text{rank}(A)\geq k+1>k=\text{rank}(A)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore the set of indices was maximal and $k$ fulfills the requirement. $\blacksquare$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Maximality is one issue. Existence is another. Have you shown that?

Comment: Is it sufficient to say, that in the case of $A$ being the zero matrix, the rank is zero, but if the matrix has at least one entry that is not equal to zero, then such a subdeterminant (namely the entry itself) exists?

Comment: Sufficient to establish what? I don’t follow you.

Comment: As you said, I need to show the maximality, as well as the existence of such an index set (if I understood correctly).  For the existence: If any entry $a_{i_1j_1}$ is not equal to zero, then $k$ is at least $1$, and a set of indices exists, for which the subdeterminant $|a_{i_1j_1}|\neq 0$.